# powershell/bat version of: find . -path \'*/Packages/manifest.json\'

Tags: powershell, unix

There are times where there are other files named **manifest.json** in the repository. I am trying to find a specific **manifest.json** which is located inside a **Packages** folder. The `find . -path \'*/Packages/manifest.json\'` is my code for when I need to run this in a unix machine but I don't know how to convert this to bat or powershell.

I tried `Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter "manifest.json" -Recurse` but it prints all occurrences of manifest.json in the repository.